# SQL Server - Repeat Characters after nth row

Tags: sql, sql-server, character, repeat

How to repeat characters after every nth Row. For example, I want result like this:

```
1 1234-A 
2 32423-B 
3 324234-C 
4 afsd-D 
5 32432-A 
6 32423-B 
7 3dsfa33-C
8 sdfw3rf-D
```

This A,B,C and D will be repeated though out result set. NO other characters.

Comment: Which `database` you are using

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Where do A, B, C and D come from ? is it from another table containing those values ? Do you need a generic solution that could work with this other table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a row number for every four rows and use case statement to append the required characters. Try this.

```
CREATE TABLE #str(id INT,string VARCHAR(50))

INSERT #str
VALUES (1,'1234' ),(2,'32423' ),(3,'324234' ),
       (4,'afsd' ),(5,'32432' ),(6,'32423' ),
       (7,'3dsfa33' ),(8,'sdfw3rf' )

SELECT id,
       CASE
         WHEN rn = 1 THEN string + '-A'
         WHEN rn = 2 THEN string + '-B'
         WHEN rn = 3 THEN string + '-C'
         WHEN rn = 4 THEN string + '-D'
       END AS String
FROM   (SELECT ( ( id - 1 )%4 ) + 1 rn,*
        FROM   #str)a
```

**Result :**

```
+----+-----------+
| id |  String   |
+----+-----------+
| 1  |  1234-A   |
| 2  |  32423-B  |
| 3  |  324234-C |
| 4  |  afsd-D   |
| 5  |  32432-A  |
| 6  |  32423-B  |
| 7  |  3dsfa33-C|
| 8  |  sdfw3rf-D|
+----+-----------+
```

Comment: Just a min, I am giving it a try!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT YourID
      ,YourDescr + '-' + CHAR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YourID) - 1) % 4 + 65) AS YourDescr
FROM YourTable
```

It doesn't rely on the value of the ID column.

Comment: very nice generalization dude!